# Check if a column (or row) is currently viewable in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

In Windows Form Application, I am using a `DataGridView` control. It has many columns and rows, so there are both `Horizontal Scrollbar` and `Vertical Scrollbar`.

Now I am wondering if there is a way to check whether a certain column (or row) is currently shown on the screen (like not hidden because of the scrollbar). 
I know you can check if the column is visible by

```
if(MyDGV.Column["myColumnName"].Visible){
    //This column is visible
}
```

but this becomes true even if the column is actually not displayed on the screen. It becomes true as long as moving the scrollbar makes the column show up. Then how can you check if the column is currently displayed on the screen?

Comment: What is it you're looking to do if it is visible vs "off screen"?

Comment: I just realized there is a property `displayed`... Thank you! With my English level, I only thought of the word `Visible`.